# Azure class library access GetConfigurationSettingValue vs. web.config

Tags: c#, azure, class-library

I have a class library shared between an Azure Worker Role and a ASP.NET Website. A method in the library needs to pull a value from the config to determine if it should send an email or not.

In the ASP.NET site, the setting is in web.config:

```
<add key="SendEmails" value="true"/>
```

And in the Azure worker role it is in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg:

```
<Setting name="SendEmails" value="true"/>
```

What I am trying to do is have my class library be able to access either config setting, depending on what environment it is running under.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your own class to retrieve configuration values and in it you'll have items like this:

```
if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
 return RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("mySetting");
else
 return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"].ToString();
```

RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable will detect is supposed to detect if you're in the Windows Azure fabric and return true. It will require that you include the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime assembly/referrence in your ASP.NET project.

I did [a blog post on this topic](http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/configuration-in-azure-year-of-azureweek-14/) if you want more information.

Comment: I have some code that works in the same way, but with a fluent-interface. https://github.com/SyntaxC4/WindowsAzureConnectionStringResolver/blob/master/ConnectionStringResolver.cs

Comment: While this was the only option at the time it was answered, the CloudConfigurationManager has wrapped this up for you.  See John C's answer for more details.

Answer (score 4):

This is now built-in to the latest Azure SDK. You can use the ***CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("")*** method, it determines if you are running in the cloud or not and reads from one or the other. This is the replacement for the ***RoleEnvironment*** azure class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx

If you are utilizing nuget, the nuget package name is *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager*

Answer (score 2):

Check out RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable.

You could write a quick "helper" class that branches logic based on if RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable returns true or not.  If true, for example, read from web.config and if false, read from the cloud configuration.